# After doing PCA decomposition, all the classifiers give me the exact same accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, pca

I am running some machine learning code and part of the code looks like this:

```
classifiers = [XGBClassifier(), DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=5),
RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=5, n_estimators=10, max_features=1),
MLPClassifier(alpha=1),
AdaBoostClassifier(),
GaussianNB(),
QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis()]

print("Original data")
print("=============")
print(features.shape)
for name, clf in zip(names, classifiers):
    print(name)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, loan_status, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)
    result = train_predict(clf, len(y_train), X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)
    print(result)
    print('-----------------------------------')

print("PCA data")
print("=============")
for pca_comp in range(1,6):
    print("PCA component size: " + str(pca_comp))
    pca = decomposition.PCA(n_components=pca_comp)
    pca.fit(features)
    features_pca = pca.transform(features)
    for name, clf in zip(names, classifiers):
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features_pca, loan_status, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)
        result = train_predict(clf, len(y_train), X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)
        print(result)
        print('-----------------------------------')
```

Effectively, I am iterating over multiple classifiers and printing their results.
Then I iterate over different n_component sizes for PCA decomposition and then again run on all the classifiers.

What I found is that once, I start doing PCA, the accuracy (acc_test and acc_train) remain the same regardless of what classifier I use or what value of n_component I choose.

Here is the output for this part of the code.
Note, once the PCA starts, the 'acc_test' is always 0.8079021551332182.

Unfortunately, I can't share the data.
But, I am looking for something obviously wrong in my code.

Thanks

```
Original data
=============
(769790, 207)
XGBoost
XGBClassifier(base_score=0.5, booster='gbtree', colsample_bylevel=1,
       colsample_bytree=1, gamma=0, learning_rate=0.1, max_delta_step=0,
       max_depth=3, min_child_weight=1, missing=None, n_estimators=100,
       n_jobs=1, nthread=None, objective='binary:logistic', random_state=0,
       reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight=1, seed=None,
       silent=True, subsample=1)
XGBClassifier trained on 615832 samples.
{'train_time': 273.7087504863739, 'pred_time': 4.388766288757324, 'acc_train': 0.848625923953286, 'acc_test': 0.8481793735953962, 'f_train': 0.877928251001055, 'f_test': 0.8775348027423189}
-----------------------------------
Decision Tree
DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=5,
            max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort=False, random_state=None,
            splitter='best')
DecisionTreeClassifier trained on 615832 samples.
{'train_time': 11.388459920883179, 'pred_time': 0.38187479972839355, 'acc_train': 0.8347195338988556, 'acc_test': 0.8338183140856598, 'f_train': 0.8735138626721308, 'f_test': 0.8728762797972536}
-----------------------------------
Random Forest
RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
            max_depth=5, max_features=1, max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=10, n_jobs=1,
            oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0,
            warm_start=False)
RandomForestClassifier trained on 615832 samples.
{'train_time': 1.3620502948760986, 'pred_time': 0.8454875946044922, 'acc_train': 0.8074556047753283, 'acc_test': 0.8079021551332182, 'f_train': 0.83979517561563, 'f_test': 0.8401815688685045}
-----------------------------------
Neural Net
MLPClassifier(activation='relu', alpha=1, batch_size='auto', beta_1=0.9,
       beta_2=0.999, early_stopping=False, epsilon=1e-08,
       hidden_layer_sizes=(100,), learning_rate='constant',
       learning_rate_init=0.001, max_iter=200, momentum=0.9,
       nesterovs_momentum=True, power_t=0.5, random_state=None,
       shuffle=True, solver='adam', tol=0.0001, validation_fraction=0.1,
       verbose=False, warm_start=False)
MLPClassifier trained on 615832 samples.
{'train_time': 130.09251832962036, 'pred_time': 8.788004636764526, 'acc_train': 0.810022863378324, 'acc_test': 0.8106106860312553, 'f_train': 0.8429408284567822, 'f_test': 0.84336348394109}
-----------------------------------
AdaBoost
AdaBoostClassifier(algorithm='SAMME.R', base_estimator=None,
          learning_rate=1.0, n_estimators=50, random_state=None)
AdaBoostClassifier trained on 615832 samples.
{'train_time': 114.49720454216003, 'pred_time': 6.846264839172363, 'acc_train': 0.8319898933475364, 'acc_test': 0.830836981514439, 'f_train': 0.8676524880554248, 'f_test': 0.866917350579005}
-----------------------------------
Naive Bayes
GaussianNB(priors=None)
GaussianNB trained on 615832 samples.
{'train_time': 2.338545322418213, 'pred_time': 2.913602828979492, 'acc_train': 0.696707868379688, 'acc_test': 0.6979565855622962, 'f_train': 0.8374139063372146, 'f_test': 0.8381986507744102}
-----------------------------------
QDA
QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis(priors=None, reg_param=0.0,
               store_covariance=False, store_covariances=None, tol=0.0001)
QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis trained on 615832 samples.
{'train_time': 17.64940857887268, 'pred_time': 6.382497072219849, 'acc_train': 0.5545554631782694, 'acc_test': 0.5551124332610192, 'f_train': 0.7616845459479327, 'f_test': 0.7619965387905216}
-----------------------------------
PCA data
=============
PCA component size: 1
XGBClassifier(base_score=0.5, booster='gbtree', colsample_bylevel=1,
       colsample_bytree=1, gamma=0, learning_rate=0.1, max_delta_step=0,
       max_depth=3, min_child_weight=1, missing=None, n_estimators=100,
       n_jobs=1, nthread=None, objective='binary:logistic', random_state=0,
       reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight=1, seed=None,
       silent=True, subsample=1)
XGBClassifier trained on 615832 samples.
{'train_time': 12.907331943511963, 'pred_time': 2.0308330059051514, 'acc_train': 0.8074556047753283, 'acc_test': 0.8079021551332182, 'f_train': 0.83979517561563, 'f_test': 0.8401815688685045}
-----------------------------------
DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=5,
            max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort=False, random_state=None,
            splitter='best')
DecisionTreeClassifier trained on 615832 samples.
{'train_time': 0.6030781269073486, 'pred_time': 0.03420734405517578, 'acc_train': 0.8074718429701607, 'acc_test': 0.8079021551332182, 'f_train': 0.8398076830188118, 'f_test': 0.8401815688685045}
-----------------------------------
RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
            max_depth=5, max_features=1, max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=10, n_jobs=1,
            oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0,
            warm_start=False)
RandomForestClassifier trained on 615832 samples.
{'train_time': 4.2026519775390625, 'pred_time': 0.5144689083099365, 'acc_train': 0.8074556047753283, 'acc_test': 0.8079021551332182, 'f_train': 0.83979517561563, 'f_test': 0.8401815688685045}
-----------------------------------
MLPClassifier(activation='relu', alpha=1, batch_size='auto', beta_1=0.9,
       beta_2=0.999, early_stopping=False, epsilon=1e-08,
       hidden_layer_sizes=(100,), learning_rate='constant',
       learning_rate_init=0.001, max_iter=200, momentum=0.9,
       nesterovs_momentum=True, power_t=0.5, random_state=None,
       shuffle=True, solver='adam', tol=0.0001, validation_fraction=0.1,
       verbose=False, warm_start=False)
MLPClassifier trained on 615832 samples.
{'train_time': 13.960830450057983, 'pred_time': 0.7337024211883545, 'acc_train': 0.8074556047753283, 'acc_test': 0.8079021551332182, 'f_train': 0.83979517561563, 'f_test': 0.8401815688685045}
-----------------------------------
AdaBoostClassifier(algorithm='SAMME.R', base_estimator=None,
          learning_rate=1.0, n_estimators=50, random_state=None)
AdaBoostClassifier trained on 615832 samples.
{'train_time': 9.310431957244873, 'pred_time': 2.949209451675415, 'acc_train': 0.807460476233778, 'acc_test': 0.8078956598552852, 'f_train': 0.8398003208188749, 'f_test': 0.8401793542652027}
-----------------------------------
GaussianNB(priors=None)
GaussianNB trained on 615832 samples.
{'train_time': 0.028026819229125977, 'pred_time': 0.019958019256591797, 'acc_train': 0.8074556047753283, 'acc_test': 0.8079021551332182, 'f_train': 0.83979517561563, 'f_test': 0.8401815688685045}
-----------------------------------
QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis(priors=None, reg_param=0.0,
               store_covariance=False, store_covariances=None, tol=0.0001)
QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis trained on 615832 samples.
{'train_time': 0.039576053619384766, 'pred_time': 0.021703481674194336, 'acc_train': 0.8074556047753283, 'acc_test': 0.8079021551332182, 'f_train': 0.83979517561563, 'f_test': 0.8401815688685045}
-----------------------------------
PCA component size: 2
XGBClassifier(base_score=0.5, booster='gbtree', colsample_bylevel=1,
       colsample_bytree=1, gamma=0, learning_rate=0.1, max_delta_step=0,
       max_depth=3, min_child_weight=1, missing=None, n_estimators=100,
       n_jobs=1, nthread=None, objective='binary:logistic', random_state=0,
       reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight=1, seed=None,
       silent=True, subsample=1)
XGBClassifier trained on 615832 samples.
{'train_time': 17.529640436172485, 'pred_time': 2.1811327934265137, 'acc_train': 0.8074556047753283, 'acc_test': 0.8079021551332182, 'f_train': 0.83979517561563, 'f_test': 0.8401815688685045}
-----------------------------------
DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=5,
            max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort=False, random_state=None,
            splitter='best')
DecisionTreeClassifier trained on 615832 samples.
{'train_time': 0.9235944747924805, 'pred_time': 0.03514695167541504, 'acc_train': 0.8074588524142948, 'acc_test': 0.8079021551332182, 'f_train': 0.8397974448899658, 'f_test': 0.8401815688685045}
-----------------------------------
RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
            max_depth=5, max_features=1, max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=10, n_jobs=1,
            oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0,
            warm_start=False)
RandomForestClassifier trained on 615832 samples.
{'train_time': 3.8425581455230713, 'pred_time': 0.519752025604248, 'acc_train': 0.8074556047753283, 'acc_test': 0.8079021551332182, 'f_train': 0.83979517561563, 'f_test': 0.8401815688685045}
-----------------------------------
MLPClassifier(activation='relu', alpha=1, batch_size='auto', beta_1=0.9,
       beta_2=0.999, early_stopping=False, epsilon=1e-08,
       hidden_layer_sizes=(100,), learning_rate='constant',
       learning_rate_init=0.001, max_iter=200, momentum=0.9,
       nesterovs_momentum=True, power_t=0.5, random_state=None,
       shuffle=True, solver='adam', tol=0.0001, validation_fraction=0.1,
       verbose=False, warm_start=False)
MLPClassifier trained on 615832 samples.
{'train_time': 17.796229362487793, 'pred_time': 1.4105899333953857, 'acc_train': 0.8074556047753283, 'acc_test': 0.8079021551332182, 'f_train': 0.83979517561563, 'f_test': 0.8401815688685045}
-----------------------------------
AdaBoostClassifier(algorithm='SAMME.R', base_estimator=None,
          learning_rate=1.0, n_estimators=50, random_state=None)
AdaBoostClassifier trained on 615832 samples.
{'train_time': 14.433330059051514, 'pred_time': 2.9874980449676514, 'acc_train': 0.8074556047753283, 'acc_test': 0.8079021551332182, 'f_train': 0.83979517561563, 'f_test': 0.8401815688685045}
-----------------------------------
GaussianNB(priors=None)
GaussianNB trained on 615832 samples.
{'train_time': 0.09282994270324707, 'pred_time': 0.06884241104125977, 'acc_train': 0.8074556047753283, 'acc_test': 0.8079021551332182, 'f_train': 0.83979517561563, 'f_test': 0.8401815688685045}
-----------------------------------
QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis(priors=None, reg_param=0.0,
               store_covariance=False, store_covariances=None, tol=0.0001)
QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis trained on 615832 samples.
{'train_time': 0.06534266471862793, 'pred_time': 0.06316208839416504, 'acc_train': 0.8074556047753283, 'acc_test': 0.8079021551332182, 'f_train': 0.83979517561563, 'f_test': 0.8401815688685045}
-----------------------------------
PCA component size: 3
XGBClassifier(base_score=0.5, booster='gbtree', colsample_bylevel=1,
       colsample_bytree=1, gamma=0, learning_rate=0.1, max_delta_step=0,
       max_depth=3, min_child_weight=1, missing=None, n_estimators=100,
       n_jobs=1, nthread=None, objective='binary:logistic', random_state=0,
       reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight=1, seed=None,
       silent=True, subsample=1)
XGBClassifier trained on 615832 samples.
{'train_time': 22.586288690567017, 'pred_time': 2.132150650024414, 'acc_train': 0.8074556047753283, 'acc_test': 0.8079021551332182, 'f_train': 0.83979517561563, 'f_test': 0.8401815688685045}
-----------------------------------
DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=5,
            max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort=False, random_state=None,
            splitter='best')
DecisionTreeClassifier trained on 615832 samples.
{'train_time': 1.3756062984466553, 'pred_time': 0.0391697883605957, 'acc_train': 0.8074556047753283, 'acc_test': 0.8079021551332182, 'f_train': 0.83979517561563, 'f_test': 0.8401815688685045}
-----------------------------------
RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
            max_depth=5, max_features=1, max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=10, n_jobs=1,
            oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0,
            warm_start=False)
RandomForestClassifier trained on 615832 samples.
{'train_time': 3.6991543769836426, 'pred_time': 0.5463252067565918, 'acc_train': 0.8074556047753283, 'acc_test': 0.8079021551332182, 'f_train': 0.83979517561563, 'f_test': 0.8401815688685045}
-----------------------------------
MLPClassifier(activation='relu', alpha=1, batch_size='auto', beta_1=0.9,
       beta_2=0.999, early_stopping=False, epsilon=1e-08,
       hidden_layer_sizes=(100,), learning_rate='constant',
       learning_rate_init=0.001, max_iter=200, momentum=0.9,
       nesterovs_momentum=True, power_t=0.5, random_state=None,
       shuffle=True, solver='adam', tol=0.0001, validation_fraction=0.1,
       verbose=False, warm_start=False)
MLPClassifier trained on 615832 samples.
{'train_time': 13.745409488677979, 'pred_time': 1.617872714996338, 'acc_train': 0.8074556047753283, 'acc_test': 0.8079021551332182, 'f_train': 0.83979517561563, 'f_test': 0.8401815688685045}
-----------------------------------
AdaBoostClassifier(algorithm='SAMME.R', base_estimator=None,
          learning_rate=1.0, n_estimators=50, random_state=None)
AdaBoostClassifier trained on 615832 samples.
{'train_time': 18.745909929275513, 'pred_time': 3.02945613861084, 'acc_train': 0.8074539809558451, 'acc_test': 0.8078956598552852, 'f_train': 0.8397946213935711, 'f_test': 0.8401793542652027}
-----------------------------------
GaussianNB(priors=None)
GaussianNB trained on 615832 samples.
{'train_time': 0.09948086738586426, 'pred_time': 0.07936644554138184, 'acc_train': 0.8074556047753283, 'acc_test': 0.8079021551332182, 'f_train': 0.83979517561563, 'f_test': 0.8401815688685045}
-----------------------------------
QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis(priors=None, reg_param=0.0,
               store_covariance=False, store_covariances=None, tol=0.0001)
QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis trained on 615832 samples.
{'train_time': 0.07803058624267578, 'pred_time': 0.07502388954162598, 'acc_train': 0.8074556047753283, 'acc_test': 0.8079021551332182, 'f_train': 0.83979517561563, 'f_test': 0.8401815688685045}
-----------------------------------
PCA component size: 4
XGBClassifier(base_score=0.5, booster='gbtree', colsample_bylevel=1,
       colsample_bytree=1, gamma=0, learning_rate=0.1, max_delta_step=0,
       max_depth=3, min_child_weight=1, missing=None, n_estimators=100,
       n_jobs=1, nthread=None, objective='binary:logistic', random_state=0,
       reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight=1, seed=None,
       silent=True, subsample=1)
XGBClassifier trained on 615832 samples.
{'train_time': 28.096595287322998, 'pred_time': 2.079728364944458, 'acc_train': 0.8074556047753283, 'acc_test': 0.8079021551332182, 'f_train': 0.83979517561563, 'f_test': 0.8401815688685045}
-----------------------------------
DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=5,
            max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort=False, random_state=None,
            splitter='best')
DecisionTreeClassifier trained on 615832 samples.
{'train_time': 1.9280765056610107, 'pred_time': 0.04021263122558594, 'acc_train': 0.8074556047753283, 'acc_test': 0.8079021551332182, 'f_train': 0.83979517561563, 'f_test': 0.8401815688685045}
-----------------------------------
RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
            max_depth=5, max_features=1, max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=10, n_jobs=1,
            oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0,
            warm_start=False)
RandomForestClassifier trained on 615832 samples.
{'train_time': 4.067602872848511, 'pred_time': 0.5436885356903076, 'acc_train': 0.8074556047753283, 'acc_test': 0.8079021551332182, 'f_train': 0.83979517561563, 'f_test': 0.8401815688685045}
-----------------------------------
MLPClassifier(activation='relu', alpha=1, batch_size='auto', beta_1=0.9,
       beta_2=0.999, early_stopping=False, epsilon=1e-08,
       hidden_layer_sizes=(100,), learning_rate='constant',
       learning_rate_init=0.001, max_iter=200, momentum=0.9,
       nesterovs_momentum=True, power_t=0.5, random_state=None,
       shuffle=True, solver='adam', tol=0.0001, validation_fraction=0.1,
       verbose=False, warm_start=False)
MLPClassifier trained on 615832 samples.
{'train_time': 18.260048389434814, 'pred_time': 2.397339344024658, 'acc_train': 0.8074556047753283, 'acc_test': 0.8079021551332182, 'f_train': 0.83979517561563, 'f_test': 0.8401815688685045}
-----------------------------------
AdaBoostClassifier(algorithm='SAMME.R', base_estimator=None,
          learning_rate=1.0, n_estimators=50, random_state=None)
AdaBoostClassifier trained on 615832 samples.
{'train_time': 24.486289501190186, 'pred_time': 3.059351921081543, 'acc_train': 0.8074556047753283, 'acc_test': 0.8079021551332182, 'f_train': 0.83979517561563, 'f_test': 0.8401815688685045}
-----------------------------------
GaussianNB(priors=None)
GaussianNB trained on 615832 samples.
{'train_time': 0.10924768447875977, 'pred_time': 0.08964681625366211, 'acc_train': 0.8074556047753283, 'acc_test': 0.8079021551332182, 'f_train': 0.83979517561563, 'f_test': 0.8401815688685045}
-----------------------------------
QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis(priors=None, reg_param=0.0,
               store_covariance=False, store_covariances=None, tol=0.0001)
QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis trained on 615832 samples.
{'train_time': 0.09738326072692871, 'pred_time': 0.08622312545776367, 'acc_train': 0.8074556047753283, 'acc_test': 0.8079021551332182, 'f_train': 0.83979517561563, 'f_test': 0.8401815688685045}
-----------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything obviously wrong in your code.

A couple thoughts:

I would expect the classifiers to be increasingly similar as you lower the `n_components` toward 1. But not identical as you are observing.

You are only looping across `(1,6)` PCA components.  Verify that the classifiers are training correctly by looping across maybe  `(1,10,20,30,100)` components.   If the classifiers still have identical performance ,  then you are doing something wrong --

Also maybe look and manually verify that something wacky isn't happening to the `features` during the PCA `transform`.  Just execute the same code and look at the new features histograms ... something weird might be happening.

Check the explained variance and make sure the additional components are adding info.  `print(pca.explained_variance_ratio_)`

Given how similar the classifiers are with all 207 `features` , it's possible they are just seeing the same thing once you run the `PCA`.

With default parameters ( i.e. very simple classifiers ) it's possible, but unlikely, that classifiers would behave the same over `(1,6)` components.

Also make sure you are looping properly ( it looks like you are) and stick in some sanity checks. Good luck !